# asyncio server client terminates early without output

Tags: python, python-3.5, python-asyncio

I'm learning to play around with the asyncio library in py3.5 syntax with `async def` and `await`, and trying to write a simple server/client architecture.

For some reason, the client never receives the message and terminates early:

## Client

```
IP = ''
PORT = 8880

import asyncio
import multiprocessing
import ssl

async def start_client(loop):
    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection(IP, PORT, loop=loop)
    writer.write("Gimme gimme gimme".encode())
    writer.close()
    data = await reader.read()
    print(data.decode())

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(start_client(loop))
loop.close()
```

## Server

```
IP = ''
PORT = 8880

import asyncio
import requests
import json

async def handle_echo(reader, writer):
    data = await reader.read()
    response = await whatsup()
    print(response)
    writer.write(response.encode())
    writer.write_eof()
    await writer.drain()
    writer.close()

async def whatsup():
    return "Hello there!"

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
server = asyncio.start_server(handle_echo,
            IP,
            PORT,
            loop=loop)
server = loop.run_until_complete(server)

try:
    loop.run_forever()
except:
    pass

server.close()
loop.run_until_complete(server.wait_closed())
loop.close()
```

What I observe is that the server was able to print out the "Hello world!", and return successfully, but from what I can gather, the client reads a total of 0 bytes and just exits.

### What I tried already

I tried doing:

```
while not reader.at_eof():
    data = await reader.read(100)
    print(data.decode())
```

But it evaluates `at_eof()` to be true and exits early as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found the solution:

`read()` will read until `eof` marker. We need to do `writer.write_eof()` on both sides for the `read()` to be read.

Here's the solution code:

```
async def handle_echo(reader, writer):
    data = await reader.read()
    response = await whatsup()
    print(response)
    writer.write(response.encode())
    writer.write_eof()
    await writer.drain()
    writer.close()

async def start_client(loop):
    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection(IP, PORT, loop=loop)
    writer.write("Gimme gimme gimme".encode())
    writer.write_eof() # crucial here
    writer.close()
    data = await reader.read()
    print(data.decode())
```